# how to find the right value of MTU Jumbo frame

Tags: linux, networking, rhel, network-interface, hadoop

We've made the decision to set jumbo frames on all our Linux machines. We have a hadoop cluster with master machines, workers machines and Kafka machines.

Our switches (Cisco) are suitable to Jumbo frame and that's fine, but jumbo frames can set as 8000 or 9000 or between them or less than 8000.

#### Questions

- What is the formula to calculate what is the best MTU value?
- How can I set the MTU value to get Linux kernel performance better?

Comment: I'd recommend https://serverfault.com/ or https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/ for this.

Comment: thx I will .....

Comment: I see you have already posted on network.. crossposting is discouraged, you should have deleted your question here first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best value of Jumbo Frames is the maximum MTU value which is supported by network device. But you should ensure that all route path support that MTU value to prevent fragmentation on some network node.

So, you should walk through the packets route path and define max MTU value. Then, set this value on all network nodes.

In Linux Jumbo Frames can be enabled by this way:

```
sudo ip link set <interface> mtu <mtu_value>
```

To ensure try this:

```
ip link show <interface>
```